# Having several directories in data-directory when using gdb

Tags: python, scripting, gdb

I am trying to use gdb's python scripting capability to automate some tests.
After recompiling gdb (--with-python=python3), I can have it to work correctly.
`python-interactive` lets me corrently `import gdb`
But ... when I am trying to load my script, I have to set data-directory having 2 directories : the one by default (containing the gdb module), and the one containing my script.
I failed doing this through the command line, and also through the `set data-directory` command.
eah time I tried to concatenate 2 directory paths, either separated by ',', ':' or ';' I had a error message complaining about non-existing directory :(

```
set data-directory /home/vdupaquis/.local/share/gdb,/home/vdupaquis/Dev/Project/scripts
```

So, my question is how to manage this else than having to either copy of link the gdb module in by scripts directory ?

Answer (score 2):

> when I am trying to load my script, I have to set data-directory having 2 directories

The `data-directory` should point to GDB's installation, and should be left alone.

To add your own directory to the list of directories that GDB Python will search for modules, append your directory to `sys.path`:

```
(gdb) py sys.path.append("/home/vdupaquis/Dev/Project/scripts")
```

Comment: Great ! Thanks for this I did not understood at all it was the python sys.path that needed to be updated. It works as a charm now !

Thanks very much !